# NFC read and write

Tags: android, tags, android-manifest, nfc

I am writing an Android application to read and write to a tag using [Nexus S](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/<).
I have two different activities, one for read and another to write, Both are to be called during their respective contexts. My manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="bri.nfc.NfcTagReaderV1"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".NFCTagReaderV1Activity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.android.nfc.TagViewer">
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="bri.nfc.writetag.WritetagActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

At my execution, the activities are called at random.. one time the tagviewer activity is called and another time writetag activity is called.

I require that my application should call "tagviewer activity" on read and "writetag activity" on write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to declare an intent filter for your "writetag activity". Instead you need to use the foreground dispatch system.

The following link sends you to a Android Dev page, which describes how to implement a foreground dispatch system. The implementation is very straight forward.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/index.html#foreground-dispatch

When the newIntent-event is fired, then you're able to write your data on the NFC tag. For writing data on a NFC tag follow this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/index.html#write

Thats the way I'm doing this within my applications and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

When your Activity Resumes you should use foreground dispatch in OnResume Method() of your ActivityClass.For Reading the Tag follow this link  [Reading NFC Tag With ForeGround Dispatch](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reading-nfc-tags-with-android--mobile-17278).And While Writing you should Again Set the Foreground Dispatch for the WritingActivity. Dont forget to stop Foreground Dispatch in OnPause Method of your Activity.So that at a time only 1 activity will register for foreground dispatch